# Does make-up with lab experiments work?

Tags: terminology

We used to say a make-up exam, how about the make-up lab experiment when we miss an experiment?

Comment: With respect to the title, the use of lipstick and eyeshadow could negatively impact some lab experiments  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard "make-up lab" used referring to a lab session missed which was to be made up.

If you're only doing (or re-doing) one experiment you could use "make-up lab experiment", generally I think "make-up lab" covers it.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd probably interpret a "make-up lab experiment" as a completely new lab (an extra lab) that one could do in order to make up for a missed one.